# VBA ADODB : replace the missing value

Tags: vba, oracle, missing-data, adodb

I'm wondering how to replace the missing values (while left join).

I mean, if I didn't get a data after the join (`ev4.D_EFFET` is empty), I would like to put `'Not Applicable'`. The NVL function doesn't work, I don't have the `'Not Applicable'` as a result.

```
NVL(TO_CHAR(ev4.D_EFFET), 'Not Applicable') as D_EF
```

My code is:

```
    RECSET2.Open " select ev1.NO_POLICE, abs(sum(ev1.MT_BRUT)) as Fiscalite, ev1.IS_DEVISE, sup.CD_SUPPORT, ev1.IS_SUPPORT," & _
    " ev2.TX_TAUX/100 as TAUX1,ev3.TX_TAUX/100 as TAUX2, srva1.MT_EA as MT_EA1, srva2.MT_EA as MT_EA2, (abs(sum(ev1.MT_BRUT))+srva2.MT_EA) as Brut_fis," & _
    " NVL(TO_CHAR(ev4.MT_BRUT),'Not Applicable') as MT, NVL(TO_CHAR(ev4.D_EFFET), 'Not Applicable') as D_EF,ev4.LP_NATUR_FLUX" & _
    " from DB_EVENEMENT ev1 left join DB_SUPPORT sup on ev1.IS_SUPPORT=sup.IS_SUPPORT" & _
    " left join DB_EVENEMENT ev2 on  ev1.NO_POLICE=ev2.NO_POLICE and ev1.IS_SUPPORT=ev2.IS_SUPPORT" & _
    " left join DB_EVENEMENT ev3 on  ev1.NO_POLICE=ev3.NO_POLICE and ev1.IS_SUPPORT=ev3.IS_SUPPORT" & _
    " left join SRVEA.DB_SEA_SUPPORT_HISTO srva1 on  ev1.NO_POLICE=srva1.NO_POLICE and ev1.IS_SUPPORT=srva1.IS_SUPPORT" & _
    " left join SRVEA.DB_SEA_SUPPORT_HISTO srva2 on  ev1.NO_POLICE=srva2.NO_POLICE and ev1.IS_SUPPORT=srva2.IS_SUPPORT" & _
    " left join  DB_EVENEMENT ev4 on  ev1.NO_POLICE=ev4.NO_POLICE and ev1.IS_SUPPORT=ev4.IS_SUPPORT " & _
    " where ev1.NO_POLICE='" & Police_donnee & "' and  ev1.IS_CLASSE_EVT=365" & _
    " and ev1.LP_STATUT_EVT='DONE' and extract(year from ev1.D_EFFET)=2021 and" & _
    " ev2.IS_CLASSE_EVT=563 and extract(year from ev2.D_EFFET)>2020" & _
    " and ev3.IS_CLASSE_EVT=121 and ev3.N_EXERCICE_CPTA in (2021) and ev3.LP_STATUT_EVT^='ANNUL'" & _
    " and extract(year from srva1.D_VALO)=2020" & _
    " and extract(month from srva1.D_VALO)=12  and extract(day from srva1.D_VALO)=31" & _
    " and srva1.S_TYPE_SUPPORT='TXGAR'" & _
    " and extract(year from srva2.D_VALO)=2021" & _
    " and extract(month from srva2.D_VALO)=12  and extract(day from srva2.D_VALO)=31" & _
    " and srva2.S_TYPE_SUPPORT='TXGAR'" & _
    " and srva2.S_TYPE_SUPPORT='TXGAR' and extract(year from ev4.d_effet)=2021 and ev4.IS_CLASSE_EVT=39" & _
    " group by ev1.NO_POLICE, ev1.IS_DEVISE, sup.CD_SUPPORT, ev1.IS_SUPPORT,ev2.TX_TAUX/100, ev3.TX_TAUX/100,srva1.MT_EA,srva2.MT_EA, ev4.MT_BRUT, ev4.D_EFFET, ev4.LP_NATUR_FLUX", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

    xlRow = Range("Colonne_1").Row + 1 + xlRow

    Do While Not RECSET2.EOF
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_1").Column).Value = RECSET2("NO_POLICE").Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_2").Column).Value = RECSET2("CD_SUPPORT").Value

        Select Case RECSET2.Fields("IS_DEVISE").Value
            Case 46
                ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_3").Column).Value = "EUR"
            Case Else
                ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_3").Column).Value = "UC"
        End Select

        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_4").Column).Value = RECSET2("TAUX1").Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_4").Column).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_5").Column).Value = RECSET2("TAUX2").Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_5").Column).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_6").Column).Value = 0
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_6").Column).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_7").Column).Value = RECSET2.Fields("D_EF").Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_8").Column).Value = RECSET2("MT").Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_8").Column).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00€"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_9").Column).Value = RECSET2("LP_NATUR_FLUX").Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_10").Column).Value = RECSET2("MT_EA1").Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_10").Column).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00€"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_11").Column).Value = RECSET2("Brut_fis").Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_11").Column).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00€"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_12").Column).Value = RECSET2("Fiscalite").Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_12").Column).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00€"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_13").Column).Value = RECSET2("MT_EA2").Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_13").Column).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00€"

        RECSET2.MoveNext
        xlRow = xlRow + 1
    Loop

    RECSET2.Close
    Call DECONNEXION_PEGASE
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the back-end database? the actual syntax of NVL depends on that. try `COALESCE(TO_CHAR(ev4.D_EFFET), 'Not Applicable') as D_EF`

Comment: @tinazmu Thank you! My database is Oracle. I did this, but unfortunately it didn't work :  " COALESCE(TO_CHAR(ev4.MT_BRUT), 'Not Applicable') as MT, COALESCE(TO_CHAR(ev4.D_EFFET), 'Not Applicable') as D_EF, COALESCE(TO_CHAR(ev4.LP_NATUR_FLUX), 'Not Applicable') as LP_NATUR_FLUX" & _
    " from DB_EVENEMENT ev1 left join DB_SUPPORT sup on ev1.IS_SUPPORT=sup.IS_SUPPORT" & _

Comment: @tinazmu I added the pictures to my message.

Comment: Seems like your question is *"How to get `'Not applicable'` for NULL values in Oracle?"* and the whole thing has nothing to do with VBA/ADODB whatsoever.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm coding on Adodb VBA, I have the connexion with Oracle data.

Comment: Yes, but all you do is "give a string of SQL to the Oracle DB, get results back". The answer to your question will have nothing to do with VBA at all. It will work exactly the same in every other programming language and context. This is purely a PL/SQL question. You should throw out all the VBA code from your question and a) concentrate on the SQL query itself, because that is all that needs to change, and b) use a *heavily* stripped down version of the SQL query. You don't really need 5 joins and a mile of WHERE conditions to make your point about NVL/COALESCE.

Comment: Since I see no error-handling in this code, and the "Not Applicable" row is the last row in the set, then I assume that you are exiting the loop because of an unhandled error (probably being suppressed here or by the caller).  I'd suggest putting error-handling in this code and then either breaking in the error-handler and/or stepping through it to see what the error is.

Comment: @Tomalak Unless the OP has confirmed the problem with another client (such as SQL Developer), there's every possibility that the problem *is* in the VBA code.  For instance, an unhandled/suppressed error on the last row would have exactly this behavior.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Maybe. I don't see an `On Error` statement in the function. But it's all the more reason to fix the query first, i.e. make sure it runs in e.g. TOAD and produces the expected result, before bunching up issues.

Comment: @RbarryYoug This what I think, the lines are deleted on VBA, but this sql code is running well on SAS. How to add On Error Statement in sql code on VBA please ? THank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query wouldn't return any rows for cases where `d_effet` being NULL because you have the following condition:

```
WHERE ...
and extract(year from ev4.d_effet)=2021 and ev4.IS_CLASSE_EVT=39
```

The rows would be eliminated by this condition if D_EFFET is NULL.

Also, your LEFT JOIN to `DB_EVENEMENT ev4` is turned into an inner join because of this condition; if you intended to limit this join to those rows with the above condition move the criteria to the ON clause.

Comment: @tinamizmu Great ! I really appreciate your help !